# Is there a way to loop a command button in a userform based off of a number input from a textbox?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

As with my other post, please forgive my lack of knowledge in this subject, I am very new to coding.

I have a userform that has multiple textboxes where a user can input data.  Once that data is input into the form, the user clicks a command button and the code outputs the data to the first empty row it finds.  This part of the code works very well.

My question: How can I loop the command button to click itself "n" times where n = data_points_textbox.Value.  My goal is to be able to get the macro to generate large amounts of data with a single click.

I've tried posts like this one 
[VBA loop through buttons on UserForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050223/vba-loop-through-buttons-on-userform)

and

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcb8b8b4-4bcf-404d-9fdb-a9d5f31f6b19/loop-through-excel-userform-textcombo-box-and-write-to-worksheet?forum=isvvba

While helpful, I am not sure these posts quite apply to my situation and I'm not sure I honestly understand what they are doing.

```
'Here is an excerpt of the code I am using, for various reasons I can't post all of it

Private Sub Data_Generator_Initialize()

'Empty Type_textbox
type_textbox.value = ""

End Sub 

Private Sub Generate_data_button_Click()

'Make sheet1 active
Sheet1.activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer data to sheet1
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = type_textbox.Value 

End Sub 

'I have about 20 additional cells that are populated with data from various textboxes but I think this illustrates the point
```

Comment: Why don't you loop inside the click event n number of times?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding, you're saying I should put the loop inside the Generate_data_button_Click() sub and just have n = data_points_textbox.Value?  My goal is to be able to input my data, have the macro input the data into "n" number of rows, change some of the textbox values, repeat the process, all within the same sheet.

Comment: What I meant is that you can have a loop in the click event that iterates n number of times where n = data_points_textbox.Value. As for the rest - it's quite vague, you cannot tell the computer to change SOME values :) So you have to be specific.

Comment: Ohhh gotcha!! Yeah I don't plan on automating the change in values, it will be user derived based on the scenario they are building data for.  I see where my lack of specificity could be confusing :)  I'll start putting some brain bytes towards that and see what I can come up with.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand the problem:

1. A button on a UF currently outputs values from textboxes to a single row
2. You want the output to an x amount of rows, based on the value of another textbox

This could be achieved by looping the code inside the macro linked to the command button

```
Private Sub Generate_data_button_Click()
Dim arr(5) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim LRow As Long
Dim FEmptyRow As Long

'Using 6 textboxes as an example. Change to your configuration 
arr(0) = TextBox1.Value
arr(1) = TextBox2.Value
arr(2) = TextBox3.Value
arr(3) = TextBox4.Value
arr(4) = TextBox5.Value
arr(5) = TextBox6.Value

With Workbooks(REF).Sheets(REF)
    For i = 1 To data_points_textbox.Value
        LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'determines the last filled row in column A
        FEmptyRow = .Cells(1, "A").End(xlDown).Row + 1 'determines the first empty row as seen from the top row (using this can cause filled rows below it to be overwritten!)

        .Range("A" & LRow & ":F" & LRow).Value = arr
        '.Range("A" & FEmptyRow & ":F" & FEmptyRow).Value = arr  'Alternative with the first empty row
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I have been off of the internet for about a month.  I think this will work.  I was adapting it to the my code and it generates multiple rows with one click!  I literally threw my hands up in the air haha.  However, I am running into two issues I am trying to work through.  1.) I have a total of 17 arrays but its only looping the first 4.  2.) I can't seem to get it to output in date and time formats I have specified for the cells.  Prior to the loop, I was automating the format using Cells (emptyRow, 3).NumberFormat = ""

Comment: I don't get the point about your arrays. My code populates 1 single array with values from, in this example, 6 imaginary textboxes. You'll have to change that to whatever your configuration is. The second issue comes probably from the way VBA wants to use US styled dates. Search on SO, plenty of threads on this matter

Comment: I apologize, that was a misspeak on my part.  Thank you very much for the assistance.

Comment: Glad to have helped! *If* this was a helpful answer, please accept it :)